# Unprotect shared worksheet OR hide certain content in a shared worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have some protected sheets in a workbook. I have a macro that hides certain rows and then prints out only specific columns with the specific rows hidden. (The user needs to see the rows on the screen but not have them print). In order to stop the rows from printing, I hide the rows. In order to hide the rows, I have to unprotect the sheet and then protect it after printing.  The code below is what I have. It is triggered by running either `Print_Days()` or `Print_Afternoons()` or `Print_Nights()`. It all works good except for one issue... If I share the workbook, I can not unprotect the sheet.

Is there another approach that might work in a shared environment?

- Can I print just the rows needed? I have tried but it prints the rows on different pages instead of all together as if it were 1 range of cells.
- Can I copy the desired content to another workbook and print it? If so, I have no idea how to do it!
- Is there a better approach?

.

```
Public c1
Public c2
Public c3
Public c4

Sub Print_Days()
    c1 = "b"
    c2 = "c"
    c3 = "d"
    c4 = "e"
    Call Print_Schedule(4)
End Sub

Sub Print_Afternoons()
    c1 = "g"
    c2 = "h"
    c3 = "i"
    c4 = "j"
    Call Print_Schedule(1)
End Sub

Sub Print_Nights()
    c1 = "l"
    c2 = "m"
    c3 = "n"
    c4 = "o"
    Call Print_Schedule(1)
End Sub

Sub Print_Schedule(Print_Copies)
    Call UnProtectSheet


Dim r As Long
  For r = 38 To 190
    'Hide empty rows
    If Application.CountA(Range(c1 & r & ":" & c1 & r)) = 0 Then
      Range("A" & r).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    'Hide UP rows
    If Range(c3 & r) = "UP" Or Range(c3 & r) = "VAC" Or Range(c3 & r) = "OFF" Or Range(c3 & r) = "NCNS" Or Range(c3 & r) = "AA" Or Range(c3 & r) = "AB - LOA" Then
  Range("A" & r).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

  Next r

 'Save the current print area
 curPrtArea = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea
 'Save the current orientation
 curOrientation = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation
 'Save the current print color profile
 curPrtColor = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.BlackAndWhite
 'Define the setting to only print Black and White
 ActiveSheet.PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = True
  'Define desired print orientation
  ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait
  ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
  ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = False
  ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
 'Define desired print area
  myPrtArea = c1 & "37:" & c4 & "190"
 'Set the desired print area
   ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = myPrtArea
 'Print the desired print area
   ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=Print_Copies

 'Unhide all rows
 Range("A38:A190").EntireRow.Hidden = False

 'Reset the original print orientation
  ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = curOrientation
 'Reset the original print area
 ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = curPrtArea
 ActiveSheet.PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = curPrtColor


    Call ProtectSheet_All_Parameters_passed
End Sub


Function UnProtectSheet()
'UnProtect Method without a password passed
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
End Function

Function ProtectSheet_All_Parameters_passed()
 'Protect Method with all the parameters passed in it
    ActiveSheet.Protect _
        Password:="", _
        DrawingObjects:=False, _
        Contents:=True, _
        Scenarios:=True, _
        UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
        AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
        AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=False, _
        AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
        AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
        AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, _
        AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
        AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
        AllowSorting:=False, _
        AllowFiltering:=False, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=False
    ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Function
```

Comment: IMO: The best approach would be an SQL behind your Excel file. There is no real protection / security in Excel (once you allow someone to open the file)! If you want to show only relevant data or data certain users are allowed to see then setup an SQL to handle the data / security and use Excel only as the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into xlSheetVeryHidden. This prevents the user from accessing the sheet, while still allowing you to print in a shared workbook. It is the third status a worksheet can have, along with xlVisible, and xlHidden. You can use code to move between xlVisible, which you need to print, and xlVeryHidden which you need for protection.

Jason

Comment: I updated the original question to explain that I don't need the entire sheet hidden... Only certain cells and only while it is printing. If I understand your answer... It will hide the complete sheet... Correct?

Comment: On the Page Layout tab at the top, set the print area to only include the rows you want. Then you don't need to hide or unhide the the rows. Then go to the view tab, click on page break preview, and adjust the breaks.